# Centos 6.5( Desktop edition ) - Skype 4.0 login issue

Tags: skype, centos-6

I have installed Skype 4.0 on Centos 6.5. When I am trying to log into Skype, it tells me that the server failed to connect. Note: I also removed the ~/.Skype directory under the home directory. I'm still facing the same error.

Comment: Ever hear of firewalls?

Comment: Yes, we do have firewall in our network, and Skype works perfectly in all the windows system expect in all the Centos desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version from skype.com.  If you're on Centos, just get the dynamic version and run the application you get:

http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=dynamic

I had this same issue, and I know for a fact I didn't have the latest version.